# Facebook API: Uploading a cover photo to a Facebook page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, grails, upload

I'm trying to use the Facebook API upload a photo to the cover photo gallery (or any other gallery for that matter) on my page.

Unfortunately, I'm receiving a 403 Permission Denied error as such:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/540282086069155/photos?url=http%3A%2F%2Fflyh2.com%2Fstatic%2Fimages%2Fflyh2-logo.png&app_id=643252662393755&method=POST&no_story=true&access_token=CAAJJCO5xW5sBAACKZBGjh9x8RfLg7krbjBA7hp0ZCEd3ZCcKvWs9NbmY3cQZBVIn3TZAcLaCZCRpYXiOU8m63lvXZBaMSWda5xOaAvbTVw6ZB9CTc8O00WGaTRZBKNYTPDqOHl35VMzNeoBNiTo251VZA2E4ZBUqouJhKTaMXyVXZAkNNg1wQ5St5SCkFn8lVmDy9oAZD

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#220) Application does not have the capability to make this API call",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 220
   }
}
```

When doing the OAuth, I requested the following permissions:

"manage_pages, publish_stream, photo_upload, publish_actions"

Interestingly enough, I can access the page and change the cover photo, but I can't access the album and upload to it.

Comment: How is Grails involved?

Comment: @dmahapatro It's a grails project. Just throwing that in there so people don't reference PHP plugins for FB :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to add user_photos in your permissions ;)